# how to remove a div from the html using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to remove a div (and its children, if its contains) from a webpage. 
Here is the ajax code I am using.

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        delete_id: 1,
        to_delete:deleteID
    }, success: function (response) {
        //Remove this node 
        $('.display_stts').removeChild(response); //It does not work 
    } 
});
```

The ajax code returns this, which I would like to remove from the page.

```
<div class="card gedf-card">
    <div class="card-body ml-10" style="padding:5px;">
        <p class="card-text" style="color:blue; font-size:15px; text-align: justify;" name="cmtSpace" id="cmtSpace">
        
            some text some text some text 
            
        </p>
        
        <div class="text-right mr-5 replies">
            <a class="card-link reply"  href="javascript:void(0)" data-stID="124" onclick="stt_func(this)">
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>continue
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

And this `ajax response` html code is in a div with the class name `class="display_stts"`:

```
<div class="display_stts" id="display_stts">
    <!-- displaying here -->
</div>
```

In this class `class="display_stts"` I have multiple elements like the one returns by ajax. But I would only like to remove that specific one. 
How could I manage that ?
Thank you for the taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Does the `deleteID` you are sending in your AJAX request matches the `data-stID` in the HTML response, or are they 2 distinct ids?

Comment: `deleteID` and `data-stID="124"` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide the div with your ajax. First put a  display style say inline in your div like this

```
<div class="display_stts" id="display_stts" style="display:inline">
<!-- displaying here -->
```

Then in your ajax you can hide after success like this by setting it to display none

```
$.ajax({
url: window.location,
method: 'POST',
dataType: 'text',
data: {
    delete_id: 1,
    to_delete:deleteID
}, success: function (response) {
    //Remove this node 
    var x = document.getElementById("display_stts");
    x.style.display = "none";
    
}
```

});

Comment: It hides the whole div. I am trying to hide only the reponse got by ajax. The only difference from all elements in the `div class="display_stts"` is this id `124 ` from `data-stID="124"`

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the `deleteID`, there seems to be no need to use the HTML response at all: you can retrieve the element having the `data-stID` attribute (with `$('[data-stID="' + deleteID + '"]')`), and then use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the DOM tree until you reach the desired element: we're targeting `.gedf-card` here.

Putting it together, the code should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        delete_id: 1,
        to_delete:deleteID
    }, success: function () {
        var cardToRemove = $('[data-stID="' + deleteID + '"]').closest('.gedf-card');
        cardToRemove.remove();
    } 
});
```

Comment: I unfortunately get an error `TypeError: $(...).removeChild is not a function` while trying this solution.

Comment: Oops, I mixed it up between vanilla JS and jQuery. The correct line of code is `cardToRemove.remove();`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Maybe you could debug this by using a breakpoint in the success callback, or use `console.log` to see where the problem could be?

For example with `console.log(deleteID);`, `console.log($('[data-stID="' + deleteID + '"]'));`, etc.. and checking the output in the console.

I don't know why it would fail at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution it will help you.

```
function RemoveJSElement() {
  var html = "<div id='myElement'><div class='display_stts' id='display_stts'><div class='card gedf-card'></div><br></div></div>";

var containerdiv = document.createElement('div');
containerdiv.innerHTML = html;

alert(containerdiv.innerHTML);

var display_stts = containerdiv.getElementsByClassName('display_stts')[0];
display_stts.parentElement.remove(display_stts);
alert(containerdiv.innerHTML);
}
```